# Filtering Row based off checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code that I was intending to use to filter a *row* instead of a *column*. I have some issues though that I can't seem to work out, at this point I have confused myself.

```
Sub FilterRow()
    Dim b As Object, cs As Integer
    Set b = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
    With b.TopLeftCell
        cs = .Row
    End With

    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range, totalRng As Range
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If

    For Each cel In totalRng
        If cel.Row <> cs Then
            cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
     Next cel

End Sub
```

The goal is to have the code check **columns** C:DX of that specific **row** for a value, if a value is **NOT** found then to hide that column. Ultimately eliminating any blank cells in that particular row.

Comment: It is unclear on whether you want to be able to collect hidden columns from the blanks on different rows or whether each new checkbox click should unhide any previous filtering in favor of its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming FilterRow is the macro that you've assigned to the checkbox, the following will do what I think you're trying to do:

```
Sub FilterRow()
    Dim b As Object, cs As Integer
    Set b = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)

    With b.TopLeftCell
      cs = .row
    End With

    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range, totalRng As Range
    Set totalRng = Range("C" & cs & ":DX" & cs)

    If b.Value = 1 Then
      If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then
         ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
      End If

      For Each cel In totalRng
         If cel.Value = "" Then
            cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
         Else
            cel.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
         End If
      Next cel
    Else
      ' Set up autofilter here
      totalRng.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Since this macro gets triggered when the checkbox is either checked or unchecked, I changed the logic so that it unhides all the columns when the check box is unchecked (ie reverses what it did when checked).

Comment: When I uncheck the box I get a Run-time error '1004' Unable to set the AutoFilterMode property of the Worksheet class.

Comment: Sorry that's definitely my bad.  You can set autofilter to false ([see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.autofiltermode.aspx)) but to re-enable it you'd have to put in code in the else part of the if statement to set up the autofilter again.  I've updated the code accordingly.